# How to activate parallel execution for OMNeT++ project

Tags: parallel-processing, omnet++, inet

In omnetpp application [mFogsim](https://github.com/rtqayyum/mFogSim) and I want to execute it on parallel, when I partition the modules manually the partition id must equal to zero, otherwise if I gave any number except zero (1 for example) the omnet through  error

the worked code

```
**Fog.router.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Broker.partition-id = 0
**Fog.user*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.ap*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.usr[*].partition-id = 0
**Fog.Fog*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.router*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Broker*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Internet.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Datacntr.partition-id = 0
**Fog.configurator.partition-id = 0
**Fog.radioMedium.partition-id = 0
```

The code that through error if I change any partition id to any number other than zero, for example

```
**Fog.router.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Broker.partition-id = 0
**Fog.user*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.ap*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.usr[*].partition-id = 0
**Fog.Fog*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.router*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Broker*.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Internet.partition-id = 0
**Fog.Datacntr.partition-id = 1
**Fog.configurator.partition-id = 0
**Fog.radioMedium.partition-id = 0
```

the above code through the following error

> Error in module (cModule) Fog (id=1) during network setup: wrong partitioning: value 1 too large for 'Fog.Datacntr' (total partitions=1)

any ideas?

additional info.

OS ubuntu 16.04
ram 32 GB
CPU 40 Logical Core

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: sir, I update the question by adding the code before and after the error

Comment: Have you set `parallel-simulation = true`, `parsim-communications-class = "cMPICommunications"` and `parsim-synchronization-class = "cNullMessageProtocol"` in omnetpp.ini?

Comment: do you mean in ide/omnet.ini file ? or the mFogsim.ini file ? because i am already added them on the  mFogsim.ini

Comment: In mFogsim.ini.

Answer (score 0):

In your `mFogsim.ini` add:

```
[General]
parsim-num-partitions = 2
```

where 2 is the number of partitions you want to divide a network.

Comment: but there is no such variable in "parsim" class

Comment: Take a look at that example: `samples\cqn\parsim`. It shows how to use MPI.